# Retrieve Slack bot token with devise and omniauth-slack on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, omniauth, slack-api

I'm authenticating Slack users with *devise* and *omniauth-slack* on Rails and I'm currently able to retrieve user's token as expected.

The problem is that, with Slack addition to include "bot" scoping, we also need to **retrieve the bot's token** and for that, we must retrieve the first (and unique) token response --as explained in [their documentation](https://api.slack.com/bot-users#Retrieving%20your%20bot%20user%20token)

Is there a way to access this response in our `Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController` ?

If not, is there another way I could retrieve this response?

Comment: you should dig into `auth_hash` which is built by omniauth

Comment: Did you find some way yet?